# Jenkins samples groovy code vs plain groovy (closure errors)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In a jenkins shared library I can do something like this:

**Jenkinsfile**

```
@Library(value="my-shared-lib", changelog=false) _
jobGenerator {
        notifier = [notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true]
}
```

**sharedLibary/vars/jobGenerator.groovy**

```
def call(body) {
    println 'hi!'
}
```

To better understand the flow of whats goes on I have created two groovy files locally (with no reference to jenkins at all):

**samples/launcher.groovy**

```
jobGenerator {
 s = 's'
}
```

**samples/jobGenerator.groovy**

```
def call(body) {
 println 'inside jobGenerator '
}
```

But when I run that with:

```
groovy "/home/user/samples/launcher.groovy"
```

I get:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: launcher.jobGenerator() is applicable for argument types: (launcher$_run_closure1) values: [launcher$_run_closure1@61019f59]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: launcher.jobGenerator() is applicable for argument types: (launcher$_run_closure1) values: [launcher$_run_closure1@61019f59]
    at launcher.run(launcher.groovy:2)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

So how much of the above code is jenkins/shared library specific? And is it even possible to write something like the above in *plain* groovy?

Or put in another way. How do I convert the above jenkins code to plain groovy?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO following is close to what jenkins is doing

**launcher.groovy**

```
// load library scripts/functions
def binding = this.getBinding()
def gshell = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),binding)
new File("./my-lib").traverse(nameFilter: ~/.*\.groovy$/){f-> binding[f.name[0..-8]] = gshell.parse(f) }

// main
bar{
    foo(name:"world")
}
```

**./my-lib/foo.groovy**

```
def call (Map m){
    return "hello $m.name"
}
```

**./my-lib/bar.groovy**

```
def call (Closure c){
    println ( "BAR: "+c() )
}
```

```
#> groovy launcher.groovy

BAR: hello world
```